# How to set datetime field in MySql using hql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am facing an issue in inserting date in YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format in MySql DB.
filed in DB is of type datetime.

I tried it :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,01);
Date startTime = calendar.getTime();

String hqlUpdate = "update challenge set start_time = :startTime where challenge_id =  :id";
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hqlUpdate)
                                 .setDate("startTime", startTime)
                                 .setInteger("id", id).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: in your entity - challange , have you used 
@Temporal
private Date start_time;

what is the error that you get?

Comment: try to add a try catch block to capture any exception to find the issue that prevents you from saving the data

Comment: yes with start_time i have   @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) and am not getting nay exception , but in DB i can c only date hh:mm:ss are as 00:00:00 always

Comment: why you have not accepted answer ?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the following.

```
.setTimestamp("startTime", startTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have specifically tried to format the date object using simpleDateFormat before passing it to the hibernate. check if this works.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,01);
Date startTime = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime();));

String hqlUpdate = "update challenge set start_time = :startTime where challenge_id =  :id";
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hqlUpdate)
                             .setDate("startTime", startTime)
                             .setInteger("id", id).executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if use `setParameter()` instead of `setDate()` ...